# @Destroy Annotation with Page Scoped Beans

Tags: seam, destroy, seam2

I have a page scoped Seam component and it has a no-parameter void method annotated with @Destroy as is shown below. My problem is that destroy method is never called even if the browser page is changed (i.e. page scope ended).

```
@Name("myPageBean")
@Scope(ScopeType.PAGE)
public class MyPageBean {

    @Destroy
    public void destroy {
        // Code runs when the component is destroyed.
    }

}
```

Do you have an idea for this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> When does the page context get destroyed?
>
> The page scope is indistinguishable from the UI component tree.
>   Therefore, the page context is destroyed when JSF removes the UI
>   component tree (also called the view) from the session. However, when
>   this happens, Seam does not receive a callback and therefore the
>   @Destroy method on a page-scoped component never gets called. If the
>   user clicks away from the page or closes the browser, the page context
>   has to wait to get cleaned up into JSF kills the view to which it is
>   bound. This typically happens when the session ends or if the number
>   of views in the session exceeds the limit. This limit is established
>   using the com.sun.faces.numberOfViewsInSession and
>   com.sun.faces.numberOfLogicalViews context parameters in the Sun
>   implementation. Both default to 15. However, it's generally best not
>   to mess with these values.
>
> The page scope should be seen merely as a way to keep data associated
>   with a view as a means of maintaining the integrity of the UI
>   component. This focus is especially relevant for data tables, which
>   have historically been problematic. I would not use the page scope as
>   a general storage mechanism for use case or workflow data. A good way
>   to think of it is as a cache.

http://www.seamframework.org/42514.lace

Answer (score 0):

do you ever use this bean in a page?, if not, I guess the destroy will not be called because of it never be created.
or you can add @StartUp to force creating the bean when the Scope are initialized.